# Selenium WebElement(Div)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

My doubt is how to click/select Div elements in Selenium using java?

I tried like this:

```
String divId = driver.findElement(By.tagName("Div")).getAttribute("Div Value");
driver.findElement(By.id(divId)).click();
```

But in the above code im getting divId as NULL.Thats why im getting IlleagalArgumentsException.

Answer (score 2):

If your div is in a frame tag first just switch to that frame and do rest..

[Switch to frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869502/how-to-traverse-through-different-frames-inside-an-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get `id` of the div Change

```
String divId = driver.findElement(By.tagName("Div")).getAttribute("Div Value");
```

to

```
  String divId = driver.findElement(By.tagName("div")).getAttribute("id");
```